# Woocommerce - manually add tax to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In woocommerce store I add manually product to cart by `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()` function.
I need add tax to this cart/product (in product menu I have selected tax class). When I complete order, I don't have tax column in order menu in ACP. I tried with `WC()->cart->add_fee()` and `set_tax_class()` but it don't work.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong, I will be very grateful for any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've always used the following and it works fine.  You need to hook into the `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','rs_packaging_fee' );



function rs_packaging_fee() {      
    global $woocommerce;
    //Set the Fee
    $materials_surcharge = '5.00';//if negative it will subtract from total.
    //add the fee to the cart
    $woocommerce->cart->add_fee( 'Metals Surcharge', $materials_surcharge, true, 'standard' );

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ){           
        return;             
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, but it isn't it. your code add fee as this screen: https://imgur.com/6sAVKH1
I need it in this way: https://imgur.com/CLMuTYo

Comment: Are you trying to apply different tax rates to different products? Why would you need to do this? Although it's not the display you're looking for, using the above you can achieve taxing different items at different rates, you just need to iterate through the cart contents and apply the appropriate fees.  I just showed you how to add the fees.